# I want to webscrape traceparts.com to download all solidworks files in their

Tags: authentication, web, web-scraping, download

I want to download all the solidworks files present in traceparts.com.
I don't know how to webscrape from these kind of login only website.

Comment: you would ideally need a login credential before scraping the website. I have not explored the website, but since it has free signup, I assume that you would have access to the required data once you signup. So, you can use that credential in your scrapping program to scrape the website.

Comment: Thanks for quicker reply. I do have user account in traceparts, but I dont know where to start for scraping these kind of login only sites.

Comment: Hello, somehow i missed your reply, apologies for the same. You can use many of the available open-source scrapping libraries and frameworks, example beautiful soup is one of them